# Ubuntu won't 'Join Displays'

Tags: 20.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors, display

Running Ubuntu 20.04

The question is exactly the title; my Ubuntu installation will do anything but `Join Displays`. I try via settings, but when I do Ubuntu will only display graphics to the primary monitor. The secondary monitor will be on, and it will display the mouse cursor, but it will display no window nor my desktop. I've tried using `xrandr` and the command `xrandr --output DP-1 --auto --right-of DVI-D-1` (`DP-1` being the secondary monitor and `DVI-D-1` being the primary), and while it does send graphics to the secondary monitor, it turns the graphics from the primary terminal off (showing only the mouse cursor). Note, the primary monitor has kept the apps bar through each test, meaning that it recognizes there are two monitors and can differentiate which one is the primary and which is the secondary. Using the `Mirror` option in settings has both monitors displaying perfectly fine, graphics et al, but that isn't what I'm after.

Any help/info would be greatly appreciated. If you need more information please let me know; I consider myself tech savvy but am no expert in this regard.